# .Net problems with remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

So i have some code, that run plugin (plugin compiled with include to references of main assembly)
This is a server objects.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime;
namespace RemoteType
{
    public class TestClass : System.MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string name;
        public TestClass(string n)
        {
            name = n;
        }
    }
    public class MyRemoteObject : System.MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public string X = "Test3";
        public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
        {
            return null;
        }
        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second Test");
        }
        public void Test3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(X);
        }
        public void Test(TestClass class)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(class.name);
        }
    }
```

In my plugin i`l try to do some like that

```
namespace Plugin
{
    public class Plugin : System.MarshalByRefObject
    {
        public MyRemoteObject remObject; //initialized on server via remObject.SetValue
        //So now i can use this object, and all will be ok
        remObject.Test2();
        remObject.Test3();
        //BUT if i`m try to do this
        TestClass x = new TestClass("First Test");
        remObject.Test(x); //!! When server object try to access x.name i`l get exception that current domain unloaded
    }
}
```

Any ideas where can be my problem?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Remoting? It is depreciated and [the MSDN explicitly states it should not be used for new development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and is still in the framework for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: I have different domains im same process, and feel better with remoting. Only this think is not clear to me. If i create TestClass on server object and return pointer to him - all will be ok